# Missing currency symbols on linux server

Tags: java, linux, fonts, currency

I have a java application that needs to display currency symbols.  I'm running on a Linux(Ubuntu) server.

On Linux server LANG=en_GB.UTF-8

The following code tests the problem:

```
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class SymbolTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Hardcoded Unicode Currency Symbol for GBP [\u00A3] ");
    System.out.println("Currency Symbol for GBP with Locale [" + Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK).getSymbol() + "]");
    System.out.println("Currency Symbol for US with Locale [" + Currency.getInstance(Locale.US).getSymbol() + "]");
    System.out.println("Currency Symbol for FRANCE with Locale [" + Currency.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE).getSymbol() + "]");
  }
}
```

gives the output:

Hardcoded Unicode Currency Symbol for GBP Â£

Currency Symbol for GBP with Locale [Â£]

Currency Symbol for US with Locale [USD]

Currency Symbol for FRANCE with Locale [â¬]

I suspect this is a Locale or Lang problem on the Ubuntu server.
What should I install/configure on the linux server to enable the currency symbols to display?

Comment: Having a font installed on a system is really only important for _rendering_ the font. Probably your server is not rendering fonts. (At least, I _hope_ you're not running a web browser on your server, memory is too precious to waste on a GUI and a browser. :) Does your development workstation show the correct output when using `http://localhost/...` but fail when using `http://server/...`? Or is the incorrect output being rendered on a different web browser?

Comment: Yeah, this is way too hazy to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is correctly trying to output UTF-8, but your terminal apparently doesn't know that it's supposed to be in UTF-8 mode. So your terminal is at fault here. What terminal are you using?

Try redirecting the output of the program to a file and open that file with a UTF-8 capable editor to verify that the output is correct.

Comment: I will verify this and come back to you.  One thought - would the output of the currency symbol for the US Locale not indicate that the problem is not on the terminal - Currency Symbol for US with Locale [USD]?  In my actual web application all symbols are displayed as their abbreviation (e.g. £ as GBP).

Comment: That's a different problem. According to the javadoc, `.getSymbol()` will return the currency code according to the default locale, in your case `en_GB`, which seems like horribly confusing API design to me. On second thought though it makes sense, it means that the symbol for US dollars is `USD` in locale `en_GB` Try `.getSymbol(Locale.US)` to get the symbol used in the US.

Comment: right on both counts.  Thank you!  Had to use Currency.getInstance(Locale.US).getSymbol(Locale.US) to get the $ symbol. Currency.getInstance(Locale.US) sets the currency type as US Dollars and getSymbol(Locale.US) sets the Locale that determines how the currency should be represented, getSymbol(Locale.US) -> $ and getSymbol(Locale.UK) -> USD

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the issue is probably related to the way you're actually formatting the number or locale rather than the font.  Check out the [Grails reference on formatting numbers as currency](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html) and the [java.util.Currency API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) for more information.  A quick way to rule out a font related issue is just to type (copy&paste if necessary) the symbol you're after into a GSP and verify that you can view it in your browser:

- ₣
- $
- ₤

Comment: He's not formatting any number, and i'm not sure what you mean by formatting the locale or formatting the font?

Comment: Perhaps you could examine the edit history of the post and see the information that was available when I answered before downvoting my answer.

Comment: Fair enough, but it won't let me change my vote until your answer is edited. And i still don't understand what you mean by formatting a locale or a font.