# NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() not returning currency symbol for Locales CHINA and FRANCE (jdk-1.8)

Tags: java, java-8, locale, number-formatting

I have written a program to return double values with the currency symbols of some countries. For this I am using `getCurrencyInstance()` method to get symbol of particular country.

The problem is specific to my laptop's *JDK-1.8* and works fine on online compiler.
The problem, I am facing is that the currency symbol for *CHINA* and *FRANCE* are represented with '?'. But for *INDIA* and *US*, correct symbols are shown.

I am working on this problem for a bit now. Hence, any leads would be helpful.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Read input */
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
    scanner.close();

    /* Create custom Locale for India.
    Locale indiaLocale = new Locale("en", "IN");

    /* Create NumberFormats using Locales */
    NumberFormat us     = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    NumberFormat india  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(indiaLocale);
    NumberFormat china  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);
    NumberFormat france = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

    /* Print output */        
    System.out.println("US: "     + us.format(payment));
    System.out.println("India: "  + india.format(payment));
    System.out.println("China: "  + china.format(payment));
    System.out.println("France: " + france.format(payment));
}
}
```

The corresponding output on my machine is:

```
12324.134
US: $12,324.13
India: Rs.12,324.13
China: ?12,324.13
France: 12 324,13 ?
```

Comment: So what are you printing to? What don't does it use?

Comment: The problem is likely that your output device isn’t correctly configured for showing the € symbol and whatever China uses correctly. Or maybe unable to do that at all.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my Java 1.8.0_91 I get `￥12,324.13` for China and `12 324,13 €` for France.

Comment: Have a look at this, a similar issue- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967430/missing-currency-symbols-on-linux-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing currency symbols on linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967430/missing-currency-symbols-on-linux-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for china use this code.
Numberformat class's getCurrency().getSymbol(locale) will return currency symbol for particular region.
    `System.out.println("China: " + china.getCurrency().getSymbol(Locale.CHINA) + china.format(payment));`

For France use this

`System.out.println("France: " + france.format(payment) + " " + france.getCurrency().getSymbol(Locale.FRANCE));`

Comment: Please explain your code and format it. If you need help, I would suggest visiting the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information about [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in Hackerrank challenge is that there is no UTF-8 encoding. Try to use this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Read input */
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
    scanner.close();

    /* Create custom Locale for India.*/
    Locale indiaLocale = new Locale("en", "IN");

    /* Create NumberFormats using Locales */
    NumberFormat us     = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    NumberFormat india  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(indiaLocale);
    NumberFormat china  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);
    NumberFormat france = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

    /* Print output */
    try {
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, "UTF-8"));        
      System.out.println("US: "     + us.format(payment));
      System.out.println("India: "  + india.format(payment));
      System.out.println("China: "  + china.format(payment));
      System.out.println("France: " + france.format(payment));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("HackerRank please fix your test terminal");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution will be like this;......

For Indian Ruppe,there is no Currency.. We have to format it using decimalFormatter as given below.

```
DecimalFormat IndianCurrencyFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,##,###.00");
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
            NumberFormat nf1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);
            NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
            String us = nf.format(payment);
            String india ="Rs." + IndianCurrencyFormat.format(payment);
            String china =nf1.format(payment);
            String france =nf2.format(payment);
           System.out.println("US: " + us);
        System.out.println("India: " + india);
        System.out.println("China: " + china);
        System.out.println("France: " + france);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution just do substring get rid of UTF-8 issue

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
/*
 * input 12324.134
 * output
 * US: $12,324.13
 * India: Rs.12,324.13
 * China: ￥12,324.13
 * France: 12 324,13 €
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.close();

        // Write your code here.

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
        double roundOff = Math.round(payment * 100) / 100.00;
        String us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(roundOff);
        String india = "Rs." + formatter.format(roundOff);
        String china = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA).format(roundOff);
        String france_initial = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRENCH).format(roundOff);
        int len = france_initial.length();
        String france = france_initial.substring(0, len - 1) + " €";
        System.out.println("US: " + us);
        System.out.println("India: " + india);
        System.out.println("China: " + china);
        System.out.println("France: " + france);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In Case if you need to **set symbol** for a currency or If you
   want to ***customize*** currency symbol, you can try this.

   ```
    Locale indialocal = new Locale("en","India");
    NumberFormat india = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(indialocal);

    DecimalFormatSymbols deciFs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    deciFs.setCurrencySymbol("Rs.");
    ((DecimalFormat) india).setDecimalFormatSymbols(deciFs);

     System.out.println("India: " + india.format(payment));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code, because above codes are not working on my laptop.
Specially for the symbol of YEN

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input --> ");
    double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
    scanner.close();
    Locale indiaLocale = new Locale("en", "IN");
    NumberFormat u = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    NumberFormat i = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(indiaLocale);
    NumberFormat c = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
    NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

    System.out.println("US: " + u.format(payment));
    System.out.println("India: " + i.format(payment));
    System.out.println("China: " + c.format(payment));
    System.out.println("France: " + f.format(payment));


}
```

In your console -->

Input --> 12324.134

US: $1,232.13

India: ₹1,232.13

China: ¥1,232.13

France: 1 232,13 €

Answer (score 0):

If your solution doesn't work because of yen symbol, try pasting that code, but in Java 7:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;



public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double number = sc.nextDouble();
        DecimalFormat IndianCurrencyFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,##,###.00");
       
  
        
        String formattedStr = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(number);

        System.out.println("US: " + formattedStr);
        System.out.println("India: Rs." + IndianCurrencyFormat.format(number));
        formattedStr = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA).format(number);
        System.out.println("China: " + formattedStr);
        formattedStr = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(number);
        System.out.println("France: " + formattedStr);

        
        
        
    }
}
```

In Java 15 that doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It might be difficult to format currencies manually. Instead you may want to create local instances via `.getCurrencyInstances(new Locale("X", "Y"))` method.

- for CHINA arguments will be: `"zh"`, `"CN"`
- for France : `"sk"`, `"SK"`

example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Solution {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.close();
        
        // Write your code here.
        
        NumberFormat us1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
        String us = us1.format(payment);
        
        NumberFormat india1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
        String india = india1.format(payment);
        
        NumberFormat china1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("zh", "CN"));
        String china = china1.format(payment);
        
        NumberFormat fr1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("sk", "SK"));
        String fr = fr1.format(payment);
        
        System.out.println("US: " +us);
        System.out.println("India: " +india);
        System.out.println("China: " +china);
        System.out.println("France: " +fr);
    }
}
```