# Query about output in "Currency converting problem in Java"

Tags: java

Everything is Ok, I also get exact output . But when I run it in hackerrank it doesnt show the "sign/symbol" of Chinese & France currency. So it is not accepted.

What should I do now?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;


class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double amount = scanner.nextDouble();

        Locale indiaLocale = new Locale("en", "IN");


        NumberFormat USA = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        NumberFormat CHINA = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);
        NumberFormat INDIA  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(indiaLocale);
        NumberFormat FRANCE = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

        String usa = USA.format(amount);
        String india = INDIA.format(amount);
        String china = CHINA.format(amount);
        String france = FRANCE.format(amount);

        System.out.println("USA: " +usa);
        System.out.println("India: " +india);
        System.out.println("China: " +china);
        System.out.println("France: " +france);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the currency symbol not showing for Yuan and Euro?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54573057/1047226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
static public void displayCurrency( Locale currentLocale) {

    Double currencyAmount = new Double(9876543.21);
    Currency currentCurrency = Currency.getInstance(currentLocale);
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = 
                        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);

    System.out.println( currentLocale.getDisplayName() + ", " +
        currentCurrency.getDisplayName() + ": " +
        currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount));
}
```

Look here for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        Currency eur = java.util.Currency.getInstance("EUR");
        NumberFormat EUR = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        EUR.setCurrency(eur);
        System.out.println(EUR.format(34));
```

This should work, assuming you actually want to use CFP and not EUR. You'll have to look up the currency codes for each currency you want.